# How to handle radio button in ant design dynamic fields

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, field, antd

I have a dynamic form field in the form where a user can add more than 1 emails and the user can select only 1 email to make it primary email. The frontend work completed and now the issue is if I add one email and make that email primary by clicking on the radio button, then I add another email and make that email primary, the previous email radio button becomes unchecked, but the value of previous email radio button does not changes when the 2nd email radio button is checked, I want to make the previous email radio button value unchecked of undefined. Check the code just add value = 'primary',

1. Add email and check the radio button.
2. Add another email and check the radio button the previous email
   button becomes unchecked.
3. Add another email and do not click on the radio button and then
   click on the submit button.
4. Now look at console input. Please guide me how to handle that issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2v1yww?file=index.js